# PostgreSQL Order by JSONB

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 10:

I have a query:

```
 select *
 from guest_group g
 where customer_id = 1
 and exists (select *
 from jsonb_array_elements(g.custom_fields) as f(element)
 where f.element ->> 'value' ilike 'a%'
 and ((f.element ->> 'servicio_tags')::jsonb ? 'person-name' OR (f.element ->> 'servicio_tags')::jsonb     ? 'full-name'))
 ORDER BY -- order by the value in g.custom_fields column with the servicio_tag person-name
 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

As stated in the comment I want to sort the result by value in the object with the servicio_tag person-name.

Data of the column:

```
[
   {
      "value":"Anton Hörl",
      "display_name":"Name",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "person-name"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"2/",
      "display_name":"Personenanzahl",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "person-number-info"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"23142",
      "display_name":"Notiz",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "trace"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"A la Carte",
      "display_name":"Typ",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "price-type"
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if there are multiple values with that tag?

Comment: You might want to use a join, instead of `where exists`. That allows you to refer to the `element` column in the `order by` clause.

Comment: Have you tried putting your whole query inside another from statement of a new query, and putting the order by statement at the end of the new query?

Comment: @JoeBanks no, how would I do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi ok, how can I do that? There always only one value with that tag. Thanks!